# iPad Safari - hide the arrow 'Play'

Tags: html, video, mobile-safari

On iPad Safari (v. 9.1 13B143) I have a strange button on HTML5 element video (the blue one). How I can remove that?

[image]

I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, It doesn't look like native button, are your using some custom video JS player for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It's not a HTML5 player issue, I find out that it's iOS interpretation of unicode character "BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE".

Seems that for this character `color: transparent` doesn't work.